# USB Pen Tablet not working on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, usb

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with headless Rasbian OS [terminal only] to connect to Parsec and technically use it as a "thin client" to Parsec by just running `parsec` command from the terminal.

[Parsec is a server](https://support.parsec.app/hc/en-us/articles/115002699012-Setting-Up-On-Raspberry-Pi-Raspbian-) that allows low-latency streaming of desktop usually for games and graphic intensive application streaming.

USB Keyboard and USB mouse works just fine but attaching a USB Wacom Tablet, Raspbian fails to recognize it even as a mouse despite showing up in `lsusb`

Is there a way to use a USB Wacom Tablet on Raspbian? I already tried this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=211665 but it did not work.

Comment: increase your chance of success by not limiting your search to Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to find out which driver is loaded for the device. This can be done by checking the kernel log (`sudo dmesg`) after plugging the device in, or by finding its bus/device number on USB (with `lsusb`) and checking

```
readlink /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/driver # bus number 1, device number 2
```

I would expect something like `usbhid` here. If there is no driver or a wrong driver gets loaded, there's usually something in `dmesg` log telling you what went wrong.

The next step will be to find out which libraries are used by your software (`parsec`) to talk to the device. For instance, Xorg appears to have a custom `xserver-xorg-input-wacom` package, as you found out. Perhaps `parsec` also has a package/library/plugin/whatever which provides the necessary support.